# Oracle Integration Instance not getting created

Tags: oracle, cloud, instance, integration, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I signed up for a free trial of Oracle's Cloud. I've tried creating an Integration Instance following the instructions at the link below, but it never gets created. I've waited 3 days. The Work Request says "Accepted", but there are no other log or error messages. Is there anything I can do to "push" this along?

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/oracle-integration-oci/creating-oracle-integration-instance.html

This sounds like the same problem found here: [Integration Instance not getting created on OIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332347/integration-instance-not-getting-created-on-oic)

Comment: The [Oracle Cloud FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/uk/cloud/free/faq.html) advises *"Contact the Oracle Cloud support team using the Chat link in the menu bar."* Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Since the [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/oracle-integration-oci/creating-oracle-integration-instance.html) you mentioned is for creating Oracle Integration Generation 2 instance. Please follow these steps:

1. Follow this [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/oracle-integration-oci/can-i-create-oracle-integration-generation-2-instance.html) to check whether you are eligible to create Oracle Integration Gen 2 instance. Your Cloud administrator should know when the tenancy was provisioned.
2. If the answer to step 1 is yes then continue following the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/oracle-integration-oci/setting-users-and-groups.html) to create instance. If you are still having issues create a support ticket with [Oracle support](https://support.oracle.com/portal/).
3. If the answer to step 1 is No then use the steps mentioned [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/integration-cloud/integration-cloud-auton/ready-set-go.html) to Create Oracle Integration instance (a.k.a Gen1).

Note: Both steps 2 and 3 will provision latest version of Oracle Integration the only difference is Gen 2 instance provide much more flexibility in using Oracle Cloud native features like [compartments](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/managingcompartments.htm) and [policies](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Identity/Tasks/managingpolicies.htm).